# Stack implemented as an array defaulting first value to 0 in C

Tags: c, arrays, stack

I have an assignment where I am supposed to use this very very simple (or so I thought) stack that my teacher wrote in C, just using an array. From this, I have to implement reverse polish notation from a text file.

In order for me to implement this, I am using a stack, pushing values on until I hit an operation. I then do the operation and push the result back onto the stack until the user hits `p` to print the value.

The problem is, for some reason, my professor's implementation of the stack array defaults the first (index 0) value to 0. Printing the stack without pushing anything onto it should result in `null` but it appears the output is `0`.

Here is my professor's implementation of the stack:

```
#define STK_MAX 1024
#define ELE int

ELE _stk[STK_MAX];
int _top = 0;

void stk_error(char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
    exit(-1);
}

int stk_is_full()
{
    return _top >= STK_MAX;
}

int stk_is_empty()
{
    return _top == 0;
}

void stk_push(ELE v)
{
    if ( stk_is_full() )
        stk_error("Push on full stack");
    _stk[_top++] = v;
}

ELE stk_pop()
{
    if ( stk_is_empty() )
        stk_error("pop on empty stack");
    return _stk[--_top];
}

void print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= _top; ++i)
         printf("%d ", _stk[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I realize that the print statement will print a value that has not been pushed yet, but the problem is, is that when I don't print it, it still ends up there and it ends up screwing up my rpn calculator. Here is what happens when I do this:

```
// input
stk_push(2);
print();
stk_push(4);
print();
// output
2 0
2 4 0
```

How do I get rid of the 0 value that is affecting my calculator? Doing `stk_pop()` after the pushing the first value onto the stack didn't seem to work, and checking that `top == 0`, then directly inserting that element before incrementing `_top` didn't work.

Comment: Apart from being an outright syntax error, `printf("%d ", _stk[_top];` also (supposedly) simply prints the same element over and over again.  Is this what you want?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how the stack works. If `_top == 0` then there is nothing on the stack. The memory locations for other stack elements still exist, but you are not supposed to try and read them because they do not contain any meaningful values.  Only read values that correspond to items that are actually on the stack. You should not pop the stack when it is empty, or try and read `_stk[_top]` .

Comment: @5gon12eder woops, I edited in the correct version. vim was having some weird issues copying that one line so I just typed it in super fast.

Comment: Also, your professor's implementation is very poor.  It is using reserved identifiers (global identifiers starting with an `_`), makes all data global (you cannot have two independent stacks) and returns a negative `exit` code that is reserved for the operating system.

Comment: @5gon12eder the logic of the stack is correct; IMHO those are minor mistakes that could easily be fixed

Comment: @MattMcNabb The problems could be fixed easily but if nobody points them out, a bad example will be taught to new programmers and they will adapt those poor patterns because the one who was showing them how to program used them too.

Comment: @5gon12eder oh I agree there, just that "very poor" is probably a bit over the top :) Having a global stack is OK for learning purposes IMHO as the details of making the stack be local and passing it around would slightly obscure what the student is learning about .

Answer (score 3):

When you are printing, loop from `0` to `(_top - 1)`, since your top most element is actually at `_top - 1`. **Hint** : Look at your pop/push method.

```
void print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _top; ++i)
         printf("%d ", _stk[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I realize that the actual top value is at _stk[_top - 1]. The problem is, is that the rpn calculator relies on the TOS being accurate. When I do pop() though, it will pop 0 and not the real TOS.

Comment: Also, I think you want to print all the elements in stack rather than just the top over and over again ? Hence the `_stk[i]`.

Comment: Any change in print method should not really affect how your stack actually works and where the top element actually is, its just that you will be seeing something unexpected. So the above version still prints an extraneous 0 ?

Comment: @Alex this is the right answer, your original code prints the element after the TOS (which happens to be 0 by chance)

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is, is that the rpn calculator relies on the TOS being accurate. When I do pop() though, it will pop 0 and not the real TOS."

Sounds like a problem with your calculator implementation.  You assumed the top of the stack would be null, but that's not the case for your professors stack implementation.  Simply a invalid assumption.

Instead he's provided a `stk_is_empty()` method to help determine when you've pop everything.

If you need to pop all elements, you'll need to break on the condition of stk_is_empty().

```
stk_push(2);
stk_push(4);

while( stk_is_empty() == false)
{
   stk_pop();
}
```

Of course in reality you'd be setting the pop return to a variable and doing something with it.  The key point is leveraging `stk_is_empty()`.

I haven't written C++ in few years so hopefully I didn't make a minor syntax error.

Comment: The question isn't tagged C++ anyway. ;-)